# Is it possible to add keyword in a vim modeline

Tags: bash, shell, vim, modeline

For example, my file looks like:

```
#! /bin/bash
verbose()
{
    [ "$VERBOSE_FLAG" == 'yes' ] && 
    {
        [ $# == 0 ] || echo $@
        return 0
    } || return 1
}

verbose display in verbose mode

# make verbose highlight as a keyword
# vim: syntax keyword Keyword verbose
```

Is it possible use syn in a modeline or is there any alternative way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't do that directly; only (buffer-local) options can be set in  modeline.**

#### option 1

If this additional keyword is not special to a single file, but applies to a wide range of files, I'd **define a custom filetype** (e.g. `mybash`), and have that additional keyword added in `~/.vim/syntax/mybash.vim`:

```
" mybash is a kind of shell syntax
runtime! syntax/sh.vim syntax/sh/*.vim

" Add keyword.
syntax keyword mybashKeyword verbose
```

To use that custom syntax, you either augment the default *filetype detection rules*, or include `ft=mybash` in the modeline.

#### option 2

If this is just a minor tweak for one or few files, I'd use a **local vimrc** plugin to add the keyword.

There are several such plugins on vim.org; I can recommend the [localrc plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393), which even allows local filetype-specific configuration.

Comment: This keyword is special to a single file. Seems I can use `set exrc` then add a `.vimrc/.exrc/.gvimrc` to current dir to replace __local imrc__.

Comment: That's right; a `.exrc` would be a lightweight alternative of a localrc plugin; see also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18933951/813602).

Answer (score 0):

Vim modelines are used to set various vim `options` (see `:help modeline` and `:help options.txt`). Since syntax highlighting is a command and not an option, it cannot be specified via a modeline. However, you can set syntax highlighting for a particular filename, file type, directory, etc. Simply use an autocommand (see `:help au`) to specify the file pattern you want to match and the command you want to execute.