# Creating multiple .vimrc for multiple languages?

Tags: vim, vi, file-type

I am starting to learn programming and saw that it is possible to configure vim through the .vimrc file. But I'm having trouble creating more than one setting. I want a configuration for java and another for C, but I do not know how to only enable a configuration when programming in a particular language.

I found the following solution to my problem:

> If it's okay to configure the local exceptions centrally, you can put
>   such `autocmd`s into your `~/.vimrc`:
>
> `:autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile /path/to/dir/* setlocal ts=4 sw=4`
>
> ([How to load different .vimrc file for different working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932012/how-to-load-different-vimrc-file-for-different-working-directory))

But I did not understand that solution.

I figured I should do the following:

1. I wanted to create a C language setting on the Desktop. So I put in
   Shell (I'm using Mac OS) the following command `vim
   ~/Desktop/.vimrc` and put the desired configuration in this file.
2. Then I put the following command in the file `~/.vimrc`: `autocmd
   BufRead,BufNewFile ~/Desktop/.vimrc setlocal ts=4 sw=4`
3. Then I went into the Shell and created a C file `vim ~/Desktop/myprogram.c`, but I realized that my setup had not worked.

Obviously I did something wrong, but I could not find the error, because I'm still noob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that you need 3 files: `~/.vimrc` and two scripts let's say `C-settings.vim` and `java-settings.vim`

In the first file, the `~/.vimrc`, you need to include these autocommands:

```
"To enable file type detection"
filetype on
augroup Java_C_Settings
    "the command below execute the script for the specific filetype C
    autocmd FileType c source /path-for-C-settings/C-settings.vim

    "the command below execute the script for the specific filetype Java
    autocmd FileType java source /path-for-Java-settings/Java-settings.vim
augroup END
```

In the other files (`C-settings.vim` & `Java-settings.vim`) you put the settings that you need for every type of file `*.c` and `*.java`

*Example:*

***C-settings.vim***

```
set number
colorscheme blue
```

***Java-settings.vim***

```
set number
colorscheme evening
```

Whenever you open a file with vim the latter will check the filetype first and the settings will be automatically configured.

---

***Note: if the setting files are not in the same directory you can rename them `.exrc`***.

Comment: which `.vimrc` have you used ?

Comment: I used the ~/.vimrc

Comment: Have you set the correct paths for `Java-settings.vim` and `C-settings.vim` inside `.vimrc` and to be more precise in `autocmd`  ?? Could you please verify it ?

Comment: I put the archive `C-setting.vim` in Desktop and put the correct path in `.vimrc`

Comment: Rename them as `c.vim` and `java.vim` better and try again (no capital letter). `syntax on` is for activating the syntax highlighting.

Comment: I renamed the file and it still not working. I can not figure out where the problem is, because no error appears. What happens is that the commands placed in the `c.vim` file don't work.

Comment: What kind of commands have you placed in `c.vim` it could be the default behavior ?

Comment: Please type `:augroup` after opening the `main.c` and see if `Java_C_Settings` is there or not in the list.

Comment: I put only two commands in `c.vim`. They're `set number` and `syntax on`.

Comment: Can you please fill the files first with the settings described above in my answer I mean with `colorscheme` commands.

Comment: I typed `: augroup` after opening a .c file and it did not work.

Comment: I put the commands that you wrote in your answer, but still not work.

Comment: Haven't you seen any changes ??

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: I cannot understand why it is not working in your machine. sorry then !

Comment: The `filetype plugin on` command was missing. Now it's working perfectly. Thanks for your help!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Use ftplugins they are meant for this.

Drop your C config in `~/.vim/ftplugin/c` and so on. And don't forget to activate their support.

(This is actually a duplicate question)