# Vim Syntastic enabling by folder

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have a proyect with Laravel and I'm using VIM as editor. I have the syntastic plugin using PSR-2.

According to PSR-2, each class must by namespaced, but Laravel migrations aren't. So I want to find a way to enable Syntastic only for files inside the app folder.

Answer (score 2):

Drop this in your `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile /path/to/app/dir/* let b:syntastic_mode = 'passive'
```

That will suppress syntastic for php when you open a file in your `app` directory in vim for that buffer.

You can read more about changing vim behavior based 
 on the file path [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18933951/5749914).

Comment: 1. If you want per file configurations you should probably use `b:syntastic_mode` rather than the global `g:syntastic_mode_map`. 2. If you want an `autocmd` to match only on certain files you can write a test against `expand('<amatch>')`.

Comment: Edited for point 1, but I don't understand why point 2 is better. @Icd047

Comment: _Edited for point 1_ - Fixed that for you. _I don't understand why point 2 is better._ - It allows you to make exceptions to the `/path/to/app/dir/*` pattern.